# Too Slow after Upgrading from 13.10 to 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04

I have recently upgraded from 13.10 to 14.04 Ubuntu. Speed has drastically gone slow, don't know why. Since I am new to Ubuntu, not much aware, what could be the possible reasons. Please help me out.

Comment: The cause can could be made by wrong or missing graphic card drivers after the upgrade. But probably for your low skills with Ubuntu I recommend You to backup your most important files located mostly in `/home/$USER` directory, and also think about some specific stuff like for ex: FileZilla connections, websites (usually located in `/var/www`), ... ect. Despite of a fact that Ubuntu developers have done a great job for the community to have opportunity to upgrade system, your case does not happen usually. Some "specific" previous configuration (or just mistake) will fail the system after upgra

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked to toggle the **Window Animations** in **Unity Tweak Tool** (install this if you haven't got it already). You find the settings in Unity Tweak Tool under **Window Manager->General**.